# If $Ax=b$ has two or more solutions for some vector $b$, then the null space of $A$ is non-trivial.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to prove (or disprove) this statement for general, real valued matrices/column vectors. I know that this is straightforward for square matrices. By the invertible matrix theorem, a square matrix has trivial null space if and only if the equation $Ax=b$ has a unique solution. But I'm struggling to see how to adapt this to non-square matrices (or come up with a different proof). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I recognize that this is simple enough that it has probably been solved. I couldn't find a solution, but I'll gladly remove this post if it already has been.

Comment: Suppose that $A x_1 = b$ and $A x_2 = b$ and also $x_1 \neq x_2$. Now try to find a vector that belongs to the null space of $A$.

Comment: @littleO I'm not quite sure where you're going with this. I mean, yes, that is the setup...but what gives me any info about the existence or non-existence of a vector belonging to the null space of $A$?

Comment: Verify that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ are different solutions then all points of the straight line given by those solutions, namely $x_1+t(x_2-x_1)$ for real $t$ are solutions as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have two distinct solutions: $\; Ax_1=b$, $\, Ax_2=b$, then
$$A(x_1-x_2)=b-b=0,$$
and $\:y=x_1-x_2$ is a non-trivial, since $x_1\ne x_2$, solution to the equation $\:Ax=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $Ax=b$ has an unique solution then the columns of A are linearly independent therefore A is full column rank (i.e. $n\leq m$).