# if two linearly independent vectors are mapped to a same non zero vector by a linear transformation then it's nullspace is non trivial?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

what we can conclude if two linearly independent vectors are mapped to a same  non zero vector by a linear transformation then it's nullspace contain atleast one non zero vector

Comment: Yes, because the linear transformation is not injective. You can check that $T: V \to W$ is injective if and only if its kernel is trivial.

Comment: Hint: you have something like $T(x) = T(y) = z$; use linearity to get $T(\text{something nonzero}) = 0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $Ax=b$ has two or more solutions for some vector $b$, then the null space of $A$ is non-trivial.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588130/if-ax-b-has-two-or-more-solutions-for-some-vector-b-then-the-null-space-of)

Answer (score 1):

$T\in {\scr{L}}{(V, W) }$

$v_1, v_2 \in V$ Linearly independent. (Here, $v_1 \neq v_2 $ is sufficient to prove the claim)

$T(v_1) =T(v_2) $

$T(v_1 -v_2) =0$

$v_1-v_2 \in Null(T) $

And ,$v_1 -v_2\neq 0$

$T$ is not injective linear map.

Comment: Linear independence of $v_1$ and $v_2$ is entirely unnecessary here (and may not be true; the nontrivial null space of $T$ could be one-dimensional).

Comment: Yes @prets. $v_1 \neq v_2 $ is sufficient.